# Select with formula that includes previous value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @sales TABLE
(
    code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    date1 DATE NOT NULL,
    sales NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    profits NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO @sales(Code, Date1, sales, profits)
VALUES  ('q', '20140708', 0.51,21),
        ('q', '20140712', 0.3,33),
        ('q', '20140710', 0.5,12),
        ('q', '20140711', 0.6,43),
        ('q', '20140712', 0.2,66),
        ('q', '20140713', 0.7,21),
        ('q', '20140714', 0.24,76),
        ('q', '20140714', 0.24,12),
        ('x', '20140709', 0.25,0),
        ('x', '20140710', 0.16,0),
        ('x', '20140711', 0.66,31),
        ('x', '20140712', 0.23,12),
        ('x', '20140712', 0.35,11),
        ('x', '20140714', 0.57,1),
        ('c', '20140712', 0.97,2),
        ('c', '20140714', 0.71,3);



SELECT code,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR, date1, 104)                 AS SPH_DATE_FORMATO,
       Cast(Sum(sales)
              OVER (
                ORDER BY date1) AS NUMERIC (18, 2)) AS SPH_CLOSE
FROM   @sales
WHERE  date1 > Dateadd(month, -21, Getdate())
       AND code = 'q'
```

---

This select gives me the accmulated sales ordered by date for the 'g' code and this is fine. 
But now I would need an additional column that calculates: 
(1+ previous day sales)*(1+ today sales) -1
also ordered by date for the 'g' code

Can anyone help with this, please?

Comment: Could you update the question with what the output would be for your sample data, and what version of SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this using CTE, just change your select query like this

`;with Sales as
(
SELECT code, convert(varchar, date1, 104) AS SPH_DATE_FORMATO, cast(SUM(sales) OVER (ORDER BY date1) as numeric (18,2)) AS SPH_CLOSE,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date1 ASC)  as rowid
FROM @sales
where date1 >DATEADD(month, -21, GETDATE()) and code='q')
select S1.code,S1.SPH_DATE_FORMATO,S1.SPH_CLOSE
,S2.SPH_close as Sales_Last_Day
from Sales S1 left outer join Sales S2 on S1.rowid -1 = S2.rowid`